Ads test beginning December 3, 2024
We’ve been exploring the concept of using open auction to manage advertising on some Stack Exchange sites. Under this model, advertisers (who have been organized into categories based on their products) “bid” for an advertising spot. There is a floor price - a minimum price for the spot, and all bids must exceed that floor price.  This community will be testing the open auction experiment, beginning on December 3, 2024.  For more information or to provide feedback on the experiment, please refer to the post on Meta Stack Exchange.

Have we ever had ads before, period? I don't remember seeing any, and a quick check from the main site, I don't seem to be getting any.
Not sure I have an opinion otherwise, without seeing the ensuing ads.

I don't see any ads either (neither here nor elsewhere on the SE network) because it can be adjusted in the settings: above a certain level of reputation, contributions 'kill' ads.

@OldPadawan - Well, I just happened to have one up when I got the notification for this comment. It was an ad for some kind of Amazon web development services. Not sure I would have even noticed it if the dichotomy of seeing both at once hadn't tickled my brain a bit. Perhaps I'm just really well practiced in mentally filtering out those things.
